# GWT - Browser window resized handler

Tags: gwt

I am developing a GWT application that render a text on a canvas. I want to resize the canvas whenever browser window resized. The problem is if I used Window.addResizeHandler, the rendering process with each resize will be very slow. So I need a way to resize the canvas only when the user release the mouse button after finishing resize. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could add a delay, so that the resize is only processed after the window hasn't been resized for some number of milliseconds:

```
Window.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler() {

  Timer resizeTimer = new Timer() {  
    @Override
    public void run() {
      doComplexLayoutCalculations();
    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {
    resizeTimer.cancel();
    resizeTimer.schedule(250);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Riley, Your solution is perfect.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to `cancel` the timer: a call to `schedule` will always cancel a running timer before re-scheduling it.

Comment: To get a little bit of better resizing feedback I tend to throttle the events. I don't cancel the timer when it is already running, that way every 250ms the layout will be updated. This makes for a better effect otherwise the resize only happens when you stop resizing.

Comment: I suggest you to use  Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred instead of timer

Answer (score 3):

```
Window.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {
        Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(
                new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
                    public void execute() {
                        // layout stuff
                    }
                });
    }

});
```